# Installing Facebook-php-ads-sdk in cakephp 3 with composer

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, vendor

Ok, im quite lost with Composer and Cakephp 3.0. Im trying to install 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk

on my project, did all modifications on composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "homepage": "http://cakephp.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {

        "php": ">=5.4.16",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
      "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.3.*"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "psy/psysh": "@stable",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "~3.0",
        "cakephp/bake": "~1.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "Allows automated tests to be run without system-wide install.",
        "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "Allows to check the code against the coding standards used in CakePHP."
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Test\\": "tests",
            "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "App\\Console\\Installer::postInstall",
        "post-autoload-dump": "Cake\\Composer\\Installer\\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true

}
```

RUnning the composer im having no changes and no installation.

What im doing wrong ?

Comment: Ok, done.. its quite simple and just found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. the process is quite simple, and JUST READ THE MANUAL

Step 1:
Update your composer.json adding:

```
       "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.3.*"
```

inside "require".

Step 2:
run composer update

Step 3:
go inside vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk and run:
composer install --no-dev

Step 4:
update your composer.json adding:

```
  "classmap": [
    "vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk"
  ]
```

inside "autoload: {}"

Step 5:
run 
composer dump-autoload

PROFIT

Comment: Step 1 and 2 is all you need.